# Shopify embedded UI does not load in the embedded iframe on initial install

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, x-frame-options, shopify-app

Submitted my app a few weeks ago and it got rejected, one of the problems was this:

> Upon installing the app, I am being redirected to a non-embedded
>   version. When accessing the app from the installed apps list, the app
>   is redirecting to the embedded version. This occurs when an initial
>   OAuth request redirect fails to escape the iframe. Refer to our
>   embedded app OAuth doc. Please see this screencast for additional
>   details.

My app is working functionality-wise, and I've been able to test with a few client stores on an unlisted install.

The UI is hosted on a Google Cloud Bucket behind CloudFare for SSL and loads fine AFTER the initial install, when the user goes into the App Page in their admin dashboard -- it actually loads as an embedded app in an iframe.

The only issue is that on initial install, the UI loads the non-embedded version. I've tried a bunch of things with iframe escapes but nothing seems to be working.